# Composite design pattern with Spring annotations

Tags: java, spring

Fellow developers, I wonder what's the best approach to implement composite pattern with annotations in Spring. I am trying to create a component that wraps a collection of other components, and invokes corresponding methods on each:

```
@Slf4j
@Repository("courseRepository")
public class CompositeRepository implements CourseRepository {

    private List<CourseRepository> repos = new ArrayList<CourseRepository>();

    @Override
    public Page<Subject> findSubjects(AcademicCareer career, Pageable pageable) {
        for (CourseRepository r : repos) {
            try {
                return r.findSubjects(career, pageable);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("Unable to invoke findSubjects on " + r, e);
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to complete findSubjects");
    }
}
```

This way if one repo fails, there is always a fallback. Implementing this with XML configs was easy just provide a list to the composite repo. With annotations, one way I can think of is to provide a custom configuration class. Is this the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just inject a list of CourseRepository objects, and Spring will give you a list with all of the Beans it knows about of type CourseRepository.  So simply:

```
@Autowired
private List<CourseRepository> repos;
```

Comment: Thought about this too, though `CompositeRepository` also implements `CourseRepository`

Comment: Ah, right.  I didn't think about that.  I do this in a few places, but I don't have that issue. - so then maybe you're right and you need some code involved.

Comment: I did some Googling.  There is a way to exclude a bean from autowiring via XML:  https://memorynotfound.com/spring-exclude-bean-from-autowiring.  But it doesn't seem to have an analog with annotations.

Comment: @Lino In my tests so far, it seems Spring takes care of this by returning only the other instances, and it kind of makes sense if you think about it: you can't inject a created instance into itself (actually now [you can](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13096) but using constructor injection will fail as Spring figures out it's a cycle). Didn't find much info regarding this feature tho', except [this unofficial article](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/04/spring-injecting-lists-maps-optionals.html). Alternatively you can use constructor injection and filter "self" out

Comment: @Steve thank you for the clarification, learned something new today :)

Comment: @Morfic Good to know Spring only injects other instances, but you still have an issue in the end client class if wanted to autowire the composite (assuming you even want a composite bean and not just the list). You'd need to tag the composite bean primary or something.

Comment: @daniu you're right, if you just want to access the repos via the composite/decorator you can either make it primary or use qualifiers. I believe the example in the article I linked, uses `@Primary`.